# One Build, Different global style for every client in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have a project and two clients,for each client I have different style.css(Global CSS), what I want to do is, I want to make only one production build,and want to serve it to different clients (with different domains), and based on difference in the URL, the global style should get changed.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: What I have tried is that, In the Angular.json, making second app, and in ng build, I have to do something like ng build --prod client1, ng build --prod client2.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try it with APP_INITIALIZER (https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER).
A example you'll find here - https://netbasal.com/optimize-user-experience-while-your-angular-app-loads-7e982a67ff1a

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: So, you want two different builds with replaced style, or one build with selection style on load?

Comment: I want one build with replaced global style

Comment: But than you can use APP_INITIALIZER to replace your style before the app is bootsrapped. You can call a function that figure out your url or path segment and replace your style.